# How to join tables for migration in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, join

I have `old db` and I'm transferring the information in `new db`.
So I need to create table `Hospitals` which contains information from `hospitals1` and `hospitals2`

```
 using (var oldDb = new oldBAEntity())
 {
     using (var newDb = new NewDbContextEntities())
     {
         var queryHospitals = oldDb.Hospitals.Join(Hospitals2)
     }
 }
```

my question is how joining works in c#. I need to take a column of information depending on `IdCode` from hospitals1.

Comment: Some things aren't clear: 1) Are both tables in same db? If not, joining would not work because you would have one context per db. 2) what columns do you have and what are the key-columns to perform the join (those columns which contain unique informations about a hospital).

Comment: in the new db we have table Hospitals, in the old db we have tables hospitals1 and hospitals2. I need to take all columns from hospitals1 and put them into the new db + column Settlement from hospitals2 in the new table Hospitals in the new db. Hospitals1 has column Idcode which is the reference with the table Hospitals2 in order to take settlement records.

Comment: Hospitals contains : id,hospital name, hospital address and settlementID                               
we take id from hospitals1, hospitalname from hospital1, hospital adress from hospital1 and we need to take settlementID from hospitals2

Comment: Ok. You should take alle hospitals from `oldBAEntity` into RAM (`ToList()`) and do the same with hosptials from `NewDbContextEntities()`. Then you perform the jois in memory and add the result to the new database.

Comment: @sprinter252 hmm, I didn't understand you. I am creating List<Hospitals> (this is a list with a type of the newDB. I am taking all the information from hospitals1 from the olddb and storying it in lets say for example var query1  = olddb.hospitals1 , but how I join the hospitals2.settlemendid based on IdCode of the records? it should be Hospitals1.IdCode = Hospitals2.IdCode. In sql the query is pretty simple : SELECT *
  FROM Hospital1
  Join Hospital2.SettlementID
  ON Hospital1.IdCode = Hospital2.IdCode             but I do not know how to do it in C#

Comment: I'm just saying that it might be a bad idea to join on 2 different DB contexts and. As a solution I would prefer to perform the Join locally with 2 InMemory lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found out other way to do it. I think it's very simple and well constructed ! 
using (var oldDb = new oldBAEntity())
        {
            using (var newDb = new NewDbContextEntities())
            {
                var queryHospitals_ = oldDb.N_Hospital_;
                var queryHospitals = oldDb.N_Hospital;
                List<Hospital> listHospital = new List<Hospital>();

                var joinResult = (from t1 in queryHospitals_
                                  join t2 in queryHospitals on t1.IdCode equals t2.IdCode
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      t1.IdCode,
                                      t1.Value,
                                      t1.Address,
                                      t2.IdSettlement
                                  });
                foreach (var sourceObj in joinResult)
                {
                    Hospital targetObj = new Hospital();

                    targetObj.ID = (int)sourceObj.IdCode;
                    targetObj.HospitalName = sourceObj.Value;
                    targetObj.HospitalAddress = sourceObj.Address;
                    targetObj.SettlementId = (int)sourceObj.IdSettlement;

                    listHospital.Add(targetObj);
                }
                newDb.Hospitals.AddRange(listHospital);
                newDb.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got everything correct as one can see in my comments. As I understood the answer this should work

```
void Main()
{
    List<Hospital> oldList;
    List<Hospital> newList;

    using (var oldDb = new oldBAEntity())
    {
        oldList=  oldDb.Hospitals.ToList();         
    }
    using (var newDb = new NewDbContextEntities())
    {
        newList = newDb.Hospitals.ToList();
    }

    var joined = oldList.Join(newList, 
        old => old.Id, 
        oldItem => oldItem.Id, 
        (old, newItem) => new 
            { 
                NewId = newItem.Id, 
                NewName = newItem.Name, 
                // do whatever you have to do instead of this
                OldSettlementId = old.SettlementId
        });

    using (var newDb = new NewDbContextEntities())
    {
        // perform your update using the joined here
    }
}

class Hospital
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SettlementId  { get; set; }
}
```

You have to adjust this with your given types.

Comment: now I got your point ! I posted below my solution which I created. I think it's little bit easier and more understandable. :)